# How can I get the location of a user's Documents directory?

Tags: c#, file-io

I want to be able to write a string to a text file on any computer. For example

```
string line = "Sample text to write"
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\Rolex James\Documents\sample.txt" , line);
```

On another system this path would be different, is there a way of writing it such that you don't have to modify the path to suit each system you want to run it on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I access the "Documents and Settings" folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752534/how-can-i-access-the-documents-and-settings-folder)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on where you want to write it, which isn't completely clear by your question. If you're always looking for the current user's documents, then you should look at the [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) method and the [`System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration value in particular. When that executes, it will give you the path to the *current user's* documents directory, which will vary from user to user and computer to computer.

Comment: I get an 'access to the path is denied' error. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're going to have to give us a whole lot of extra information then. What type of app is it, how is it running, etc. Also update your post to show the code you're running now (or create a new post, since this is almost certainly a different issue)

Comment: It worked. I was writing to a directory instead of a file. Thanks